# Prevent a task to run before it started

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, scheduled-tasks

Hello I've created a TimerTask that is setup to be launched after 5s but in my app the user can do something that must prevent this task to run. How do i cancel the task before the timer ends and prevent it from ever happening?

Here is my code:

```
val time = Timer("Timer",false)

    Timber.tag("COMPOSABLE23").d(fingerprintFingerCount.name)
    fun test(){
        Timber.tag("COMPOSABLE24").d(fingerprintFingerCount.name)
        if (fingerprintFingerCount.name == FingerprintScanStatus.ScanFew.name){
            Timber.tag("COMPOSABLE2").d("Manger encore")
        }
    }

        if (fingerprintFingerCount.name == FingerprintScanStatus.ScanFew.name){
            Timber.tag("COMPOSABLE2").d("Manger")
            time.schedule(5000){
                test()
            }
        }else if(fingerprintFingerCount.name == FingerprintScanStatus.ScanNotStarted.name){
            time.cancel()
        }
```

Comment: You could just eliminate your `else if` branch and not schedule the timer in the first place if you aren't going to use it.

Comment: The objective is to set the timer for when someone is putting his finger on a fingerprint reader and stop it when he removes it. so i cant just not schedule the timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a `var` property for the TimerTask as a nullable type. And keep your timer in a property, too, for robustness/organization reasons.

```
private val timer = Timer("Timer", false)
private var timerTask: TimerTask? = null
```

When you create the TimerTask, cancel any previous one just in case. Create the timer by setting the property. Then schedule it. This way, you are keeping a reference to it in the property so you can cancel it later if you need to.

```
timerTask?.cancel()
timerTask = object: TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        test()
    }
}
timer.schedule(timerTask, delay = 5000L)
```

When you need to cancel it, you just need to call `timerTask?.cancel()`.